# Json Deserialized Object

Tags: c#, json, xamarin

My model :

```
public class RootObject
{
    public double Balance { get; set; }
    public string CardCode { get; set; }
    public string CardName { get; set; }
    public string PriceLevel { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
}
```

My Json Response:

```
var response = "{\"C0001\":{\"Balance\":3.01,\"CardCode\":\"C0001\",\"CardName\":\"Mubarik\",\"PriceLevel\":\"PL1\",\"Status\":true}}"
```

How can I Deserialized this response to the following Model.

Comment: A good way to use JSON in C# is with [JSON.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Answer (score 0):

One of possible solutions is:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, RootObject>>(response);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54385322/7775908 is worth noticing because it's also working as expected.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve it using `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject` like following code.

```
var response = "{\"C0001\":{\"Balance\":3.01,\"CardCode\":\"C0001\",\"CardName\":\"Mubarik\",\"PriceLevel\":\"PL1\",\"Status\":true}}";
JObject search = JObject.Parse(response);
RootObject yourObject = search["C0001"].ToObject<RootObject>();
```

[Online Demo](https://rextester.com/GCDL28796)

**Output**

[image]

To read more about partial JSON fragment deserialization you can check [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSONFragments.htm)

**EDIT:**

> what about this response? var bp =
>   "{\"C0001\":{\"Balance\":3.01,\"CardCode\":\"C0001\",\"CardName\":\"Mubarik\",\"PriceLevel\":\"PL1\",\"Status\":true},\"C0002\":{\"Balance\":1.03,\"CardCode\":\"C0001\",\"CardName\":\"Richie
>   Rich\",\"PriceLevel\":\"PL2\",\"Status\":true}}" – Mubah Mohamed

As per the format in the comment where you're getting multiple object in JSON with different ID, you can try like following to convert it into a list of `RootObject`.

```
 var response = "{\"C0001\":{\"Balance\":3.01,\"CardCode\":\"C0001\",\"CardName\":\"Mubarik\",\"PriceLevel\":\"PL1\",\"Status\":true},\"C0002\":{\"Balance\":1.03,\"CardCode\":\"C0001\",\"CardName\":\"Richie Rich\",\"PriceLevel\":\"PL2\",\"Status\":true}}";
 JObject search = JObject.Parse(response);
 IList<JToken> results = search.Children().ToList();
 List<RootObject> searchResults = new List<RootObject>();
 foreach (JToken result in results)
  {
    RootObject searchResult = result.First.ToObject<RootObject>();
    searchResults.Add(searchResult);
  }
```

[Online Demo](https://rextester.com/WWXJ24677)

Comment: Imho `RootObject yourObject = search["C0001"].ToObject<RootObject>();` looks better. P.S. I'm not a downvoter

Comment: thanks @woldemar, you are right, I have updated the answer.

Comment: what about this response?
`var bp = "{\"C0001\":{\"Balance\":3.01,\"CardCode\":\"C0001\",\"CardName\":\"Mubarik\",\"PriceLevel\":\"PL1\",\"Status\":true},\"C0002\":{\"Balance\":1.03,\"CardCode\":\"C0001\",\"CardName\":\"Richie Rich\",\"PriceLevel\":\"PL2\",\"Status\":true}}"`

Comment: In this case what do you want? do you want to get it as a list?

Comment: @MubahMohamed I have updated the answer, please check and let me know if it resolved your problem or not.

Comment: still Not Working

Comment: check this online demo https://rextester.com/WWXJ24677 and let me know what is the issue?

Comment: I am Using C# on Xamarin

Comment: What error you are getting? I can’t guess the issue. You need to provide more detail about what is not working and what error you are getting

Comment: i am unable to return Deserialized Json Objects

`public async Task<List<Partner>> pullPartner()
{
 string Url = "https://bloodbank-3fcd8.firebaseio.com/Partner.json";
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
 HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, Url);
 HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage);

 var bp = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

 return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Partner>>(bp);
}`

Partner is RootObject

Comment: Its Not Working.

Comment: Its not working is not going to help, you should be telling what error/exception you are getting. How do I know what is the problem.

Comment: can i contact you via twitter

Comment: The Code above Works